# FInd the set of all complex numbers that satisfy argument inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

The inequality given is as stated bellow:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}< \arg\left(\frac{z-i}{z+i}\right) \le \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

There are not any other constraints except $z\ne-i$.
I tried letting $z=x+yi$, which leads to:
$\frac{\pi}{2}<\arctan\big(\frac{2x}{x²+y²-1}\big)\le \frac{3\pi}{4}$, which I tried solving as:
$\frac{2x}{x²+y²-1}\le-1$ for the right part but I got stuck. Is this the correct away to approach this problem?

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture of $\{w : \pi/2 < \operatorname{arg} w \le 3\pi/4\}$.  Examine how the linear fractional transformation $w = (z-i)/(z+i)$ transforms it.

Comment: @GEdgar Something tells me that I may be over my head.  That is, it may be that my analysis is either incomplete or much less elegant than it needs to be.  If there is a better way, then I will delete my answer.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the correct way.  The only mistake that you made is that you focused on the tangent, rather than focusing explicitly on both the cosine and sine.

$\pi/2 < \theta \leq 3\pi/4 \implies $

- $\cos(\theta) < 0.$
- $\sin(\theta) > 0.$
- $\sin(\theta) \geq | ~\cos(\theta) ~|.$

The above constraints can be somewhat streamlined by

- $~\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \sin(\theta) < 1.$
- $~\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \cos(\theta) < 0.$

However (strangely enough), the first set of constraints above will be easier to deal with, for this problem, because it will allow you to **ignore the denominator** (explained below).

Starting from scratch:

$$\frac{x + i(y-1)}{x + i(y+1)} \times 
\frac{x - i(y+1)}{x - i(y+1)} = $$

$$\frac{[ ~x^2 + (y^2 - 1) ~] + i[-2x]}{\text{some positive real number - who cares}}. \tag1 $$

**Note**:
If $\displaystyle ~z = \frac{x + iy}{s} ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R}, ~s \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ then the standard approach is to re-express $~z~$ as

$$z = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}{s} \times \frac{x + iy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}},$$

so that the argument to $~z~$ is the angle $~\theta~$ that has $~\displaystyle \cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, ~\sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.$

In this problem, since it is sufficient to interrogate the signs of $~\cos(\theta),~$ and $~\sin(\theta),~$ and the *relative sizes* of $~\cos(\theta)~$ and $~\sin(\theta),~$ the denominator in (1) above can be ignored.

To satisfy the original constraints, you need:

- $[-2x] > 0 \implies x < 0.$
- $[x^2 + y^2 - 1] < 0 \implies $ 
  $y^2 < 1 - x^2.$
- $~(-2x) \geq 1 - (x^2 + y^2) \implies $ 
  $y^2 \geq 1 - x^2 + 2x.$

Since $~x^2 + y^2 < 1,~$ you must have that 
$~-1 < x < 0.$

Then, $~y~$ can be positive or negative, but you must have:

- $y^2 < 1 \implies |y| < 1.$
- $1 - x^2 + 2x \leq y^2 < 1 - x^2.$